# show last posts of single category and ordering by meta with mysql_query in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have a wordpress query like this

```
query_posts( 'cat=100&posts_per_page=3&meta_key=views&orderby=date,meta_value&order=DESC' );
```

in this code , i slected last 3post of special category 100 ( ordered by values of views meta key

i need to run this code out of wordpress area ( out of theme or plugins ) so i need to use `mysql_query`

i tried a lot to join category , but i can't do it

here is details of `WordPress_Taxonomy` database relations and `query_posts`
https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Taxonomy

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: Dump the global WP_Query and you'll see the SQL query that was used to retrieve the posts :)

Comment: @NathanDawson thank you , but `var_dump($WP_Query);` return this `public 'request' => string 'SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND 0 = 1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'views' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3'` this sql command not working alos i can't see category joins in this code